# How to define chart order when exporting from Excel to PowerPoint?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have created a sheet where all the charts are located, and then I used a macro to export the charts into a PowerPoint.

How to define the order in which the charts are inserted into the presentation? I tried by naming them Chart 1, Chart 2, etc. but it did not work.

Here is the macro code:

```
 'First we declare the variables we will be using
Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

'Look for existing instance
On Error Resume Next
Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

'Let's create a new PowerPoint
If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
    Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
End If
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
    newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
End If

'Show the PowerPoint
newPowerPoint.Visible = True

'Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides._
Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View._
GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation._
Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
    cht.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"

'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
    'activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 1
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 1

    'activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
    'activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 505

Next

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the charts Chart1, Chart2, etc., you simply need to adjust your loop to do the charts in the order you named them.

Declare iCht as a Long, then change the loop to:

`For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart" & CStr(iCht))`

I think the rest of your code stands.